# Reading and splitting data from a text file

Tags: java

So I have a text file that looks like this...

```
4234
Bob

6858
Joe
```

I am trying to read the file with java and insert the data into an array. I want to separate the data by that empty line (space). Here is the code that I have come up with to solve the issue, but I am not quite there.

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // This name is used when saving the file
    BufferedReader input;
    String inputLine;
    try {
      input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
      while ((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputLine.split(" ")));
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

The issue that I am coming across is that the output from the code above looks something like this

```
[4234]
[Bob]
[]
[6858]
[Joe]
```

The outcome that I would like to achieve, and for the life of me can't think of how to accomplish, is

```
[4234, Bob]
[6858, Joe]
```

I feel like with many things that it is a relatively simple code change; I am just not sure what that is.

Comment: You started well. You have to check if each line is empty or not. Also for each line you have to check if is a number or a text and create array with each pair [number, text]

Comment: @MihaiCatan Okay doesn't sound too bad. This is just a small example a bigger problem where I have multiple lines of strings. How do I differentiate them then we the types will he the same?

Comment: You can have 2 arrays, one for strings and one for numbers. At the end of parsing the file, combine the 2 arrays by index and hopefully will get the correct output, if the file has the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

Your way of reading the file is not most convenient, in this case.. `Scanner` would have eased all this work; however, if you *insist*, that you want to use `BufferedReader` and `FileReader`, it's going to be a bit verbose, boilerplate and even ugly code, something like this:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This name is used when saving the file
        BufferedReader input;
        String inputLine;
        String answer = "";
        try {
            input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path\\to\\your\\test.txt"));
            while ((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
                answer = answer + "[" + inputLine + ", ";
                while ((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null && !inputLine.equals("")) {
                    answer += inputLine;
                }
                answer += "]";
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = "";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

This code, with `test.txt` containing:

```
4234
Bob

6858
Joe

4234
John

5352
Martin
```

will output:

```
[4234, Bob]
[6858, Joe]
[4234, John]
[5352, Martin]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

- 2D array
- Logic to keep track of where you are in the array position
- If your Line is a Number/String

This sounds like hw :) so I wont be solving it, I will just help a bit.

```
String[][] myData = define your 2D array;
```

//You need to create a consumer.  This is what will take the String line, figure out where to put it into your 2D array.

```
    Consumer<String> processLine = (line) ->  {
        if(StringUtils.isNumeric(line)){
            //Put into array[counter][1]
        }
        else{
            //its a String
            //Put into array[counter][0]
        }
    };
```

The below try/catch, Opens a File, Reads its Lines, and goes over each one in order (forEachOrdered), ignoring all empty lines, and send it to your processLine consumer.

```
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:/example.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset())) {
        lines.filter(line -> !line.isEmpty()).forEachOrdered(processLine);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        //Handle Exception
    }
```

Used Apache StringUtils http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

IF you dont want to use any external Libs. You can probably do

`Integer.parseInt(line)` <-- If that throws an exception, its not a number

Comment: You are correct. It is part of HW. It is not the main point of the HW though just something on the side that I was trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's an actual requirement for you to use arrays of strings, but the better way in the long run is to create a class.

```
class Person {
 public String id;
 public String name;
 public String toString() { return String.format("[%s, %s]", id, name); }
}
```

(note: It's a bad idea to actually make the fields public, but this makes the code shorter. You should probably use getters and setters).

Now you can create `Person`s while reading the file.

```
List<Person> allInFile = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path\\to\\your\\test.txt"))) {
  String line = reader.readLine();
  while (line != null) {
    line = line.trim();
    // ignore empty lines
    if (line.length() == 0) {
      continue;
    }
    // this is an id; create a person and assign id
    Person person = new Person();
    person.id = line;
    // read consecutive field, which is the name
    person.name = reader.readLine();
    // add the person to the list
    allInFile.add(person);
  }
}
allInFile.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Lots of improvements to be done on this, but the main point is to put the two data points into a class.

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this code:**
it work only when file contains **number** followed by **name** otherwise pair would be different format

**pair : [number, string]**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader input;
        String inputLine;
        List<String> pair = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Test.txt"));

            while ((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!inputLine.isEmpty()) {
                    pair.add(inputLine);
                }
                if (pair.size() == 2) {
                    list.add(pair.toString());
                    pair.clear();
                }
            }
            for (String s : list) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the answers posted by my fellow Stack Overflow members I figured out that there was a very simple way of solving this issue and that was by using `Scanner` rather than using `BufferedReader`. I am not sure why I didn't think of this before, but hindsight is 2020. Anyway, the code below is what I used to solve my issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
  File file = new File("test.txt");
  try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
      test.add(sc.next()); // The id
      test.add(sc.next()); // The name
    }
    sc.close();
    System.out.println(test.toString());
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

All this is doing is getting each line with the different data on it and is skipping the blank. From there it is adding it to an `ArrayList` for later processing. Remember K.I.S.S (Keep It Simple Stupid) no need to overcomplicate anything.